# I accidentally deleted my /root folder and now my shell string is different. What gives?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, putty

I stupidly managed to delete my `/root` folder on CentOS. I re-created an empty /root folder and set root privs to it, but now my shell string in PuTTY is different.

Whereas it used to say `[root@servername ~]$`, now it just says `-bash-4.1#`.

What has happened? Have I deleted anything important inside `/root`? How can I restore the previous string?

Comment: This is a reminder of why good, accessible backups are important.  But of course, you already knew that. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably deleted a `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file - these are hidden by default from `ls`. You could create a new `.bashrc` in `/root` with something like `PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$`, which would give you something similar to what you lost.

If you would like to get `/root` set up much the same as the initial install, instead of creating an empty `/root` you could `cp -a /etc/skel /root` - this would copy over all of the default user account files, which is likely what your distro does during the initial install. These files would include a `.bash_profile`, etc, specific to the distro.

Comment: Ah awesome. Can I copy this from one of my other user accounts (which still do have the correct shell string)? Or is there something "special" about root's?

Comment: I've noticed that it tends to be slightly different from the `/home/<user>/` files, but the default configuration is pretty distribution specific.

Comment: Well it certainly worked. Thanks so much. I'll accept the answer as soon as it's possible to do so.

Answer (score 3):

For CentOS 6 I added back 2 default files of `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` with the following:

`-bash-4.1# vim .bashrc`

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

`-bash-4.1# vim .bash_profile`

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Now mine looks correct `[root@bvdirect-db-dev ~]#`

Hope this helps!